# Fixed Effect vs Random Effect Output

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am currently a statistics student taking an designing experiments class.  At this point I feel I am getting a good grip on when to choose between a fixed effects, random effects, and mixed effects model. But one of the questions my teacher always asks is how the findings would be different if I had chosen a different ANOVA model.  I am never sure how to answer this.